# Detect media (image, video) type by URL

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Based on the URL I need to show either `<img>` or `<video>`. Is there a way to detect the media type based on the URL? Or maybe there is some generic html tag that allows to view both image and video? And there is no specific file extension at the end of the URL.

Comment: Is there a sample `URL` you can give

Comment: Check the extension of file will be the easiest way

Comment: I don't know how many possible extension can be at the end of the URL. It can be jpg, mp4 and lots of other known or unknown formats. I just know that there are only images and videos

Comment: @msanford probably I'll do as you offered. I think you can write it as an answer.

Comment: @AraratHarutyunyan Done, as a minimal example.

Comment: Extensions mean nothing, they are just a convention.  I could just as easily name a text file `foo.mp4`.  Mime types can lie too.  If you are trying to use a `<video>` tag, let the browser try and figure it out for you as it is supposed to do.  What ***exactly*** is your problem in such that you think you need to determine the file type yourself?

Comment: @zero298 My problem is the following. I get some URLs from the back-end and I know they are either image or video URLs. So in HTML I need to know which tag to use `img` or `video`. I tried using `video` tag for both cases and it doesn't work. I tried using `img` tag for both and it seems to work only on Safary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution in which you extract the extension from the URL and search a [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to match element type to extension:

```
const types = new Map([["jpg", "img"], ["gif", "img"], ["mp4", "video"], ["3gp", "video"]])

const url = new URL("http://example.com/image.jpg")
const extension = url.pathname.split(".")[1]

const element = document.createElement(types.get(extension))
element.src = url
```

---

*Original answer*

Make two lists of file extensions that map to img and video files. Store these as two arrays.

When you encounter the URL - user input, JSON from REST, whatever - find the extension in the URL and see which list it belongs to.

Then create your element and inject the URL into its source, such as:

```
const images = ["jpg", "gif", "png"]
const videos = ["mp4", "3gp", "ogg"]

const url = new URL("http://example.com/image.jpg")
const extension = url.pathname.split(".")[1]

if (images.includes(extension)) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
} else if (videos.includes(extension)) {
  let video = document.createElement('video');
  video.src = url;
}
```

This is not an especially robust solution: perhaps your paths have dots in them, but at least the use of [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) will extract the file portion of a URL that might have parameters.

Note that [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) takes any DOM node as a parent, it doesn't have to be `document`.

Comment: I'd like to mention that it's a good case to use `Set` instead of `array`.

Comment: Better suggestion would be `Map()`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is pointing to a native file on a remote server, such as a JPG, PNG, or other image (Same for video) than you can to a Split on the last period and grab the extension.

Then once the extension is known, you can perform logic to determine if it's an image extension, or a video extension.

Otherwise, you would just initiate a programmatic download of the file and then perform the same check.